# Determining coordinates of a triangles vertex knowing the other two vertices and the triangles inradius

Tags: geometry, triangles

Known values: $A = (x_{1}, y_{1})$, $B = (x_{2}, y_{2})$, and $r$ is the inradius of $\Delta ABC$. $\Delta ABC$ will always be scalene.

What are the coordinates of $C$? Do we have enough information to determine this?

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but it's going to get closed unless you post what you've done on it.

Comment: My gut reaction is that $r$ will determine the coordinates of $C$, but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: yes, draw tangent lines from incircle and find the intersection of the two lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course not. Take $I$ (the incenter) on a line whose distance from $AB$ is $r$, between the projections of $A$ and $B$ on such a line.
The symmetric of $AB$ with respect to $AI$ and the symmetric of $AB$ with respect to $BI$ will meet at a candidate $C$-point. The locus of such $C$s is a hyperbola:
[image]

Comment: This is interesting. I was assuming that it wouldn't be possible at all. However, with further restrictions on the problem (e.g. $BC$ must be parallel with the $x$-axis, which is actually a reasonable restriction for my problem) that should allow us to solve the problem, right?

Comment: @Bidski: of course, if you know the $\widehat{ABC}$ angle then the position of $I$ is fixed and so it is fixed the position of $C$.